# Is there a way to change/override settings in launchSettings.json without having to commit them?

Tags: asp.net-core, debugging, .net-core

I do not like having a browser launched every time I try to debug an application. I particularly do not like that closing the browser stops debugging, and that stopping debugging closes the browser. Others in my team do like that behaviour, and that's how launchSettings.json is set up.

Is there any way to override all or part launchSettings.json without having to change launchSettings.json itself? I suppose I could make the change locally and then remember to never commit the file, but that risks committing it and not realising that I've done so (and it also just feels yucky). appsettings.json can be overridden just for me with an ignored appsettings.Development.json, but I can't find any analogue for launchSettings.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short - no. Path to `launchSettings.json` [is hardcoded in multiple `dotnet` commands](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/c65620ccd6057845ef38cd8cfe6c3fb178a0b7c1/src/Cli/dotnet/commands/dotnet-run/RunCommand.cs#L141) and you can't change it.

You have another option though - create custom launchSettings profile. Copy-paste existing one (the one you are using) in the `profiles` property, rename it and set `launchBrowser` to false and use the new profile to run.

If you are using Rider (C# IDE from JetBrains) you can use it's ability to have multiple [changelists](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Managing_Changelists.html#active-changelist), modify the `launchSettings.json` and move it to another (new) changelist (I quite often do this with settings which I don't want to commit). Note that changelists will work only via the Rider version control tools.

Read more:

- [Development and launchSettings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0#development-and-launchsettingsjson)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to don't commit `launchSettings.json` you can add `.vscode` folder or `launchSettings.json` file to `.gitignore` then remove cache it from git by this code:

```
git rm --cached -r  FilePath
```

**Notice :** when you remove file from cache of `git`, it is not push and exist in your repository