ASP.NET Core Web API launches on a wrong Url
I am using EF Core, and after making some changes to the models and DbContext and running
dotnet ef database update -p Project_Name

when I run the API, it launches a different url; it should run on https://0.0.0.0:7118, but it runs on https://localhost:54854.
My launchsettings.json looks like this:
(https://i.sstatic.net/242d7.png)
and the server looks like this:
(https://i.sstatic.net/7YzVh.png)
Also swagger does not start with this error:

This localhost page can’t be found - no webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:54854/

(https://i.sstatic.net/D0fAC.png)
I checked the build action for launchsettings.json and it is set to Content.

Does this issue occur when testing locally in VS? Or it happened after you published it to  somewhere else? According to the symptom, the port might be covered. Could you pls check this case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70332897/how-to-change-default-port-no-of-my-net-core-6-api   By the way, have you tried to clean the project and test again?

@TinyWang this occurs when testing locally on VS and after adding
"Kestrel": {
"Endpoints": {
"Http": {
"Url": "http://0.0.0.0:5222"
},
"Https": {
"Url": "https://0.0.0.0:7118"
}
}
} to appsettings.json it gives me this warning:
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
Overriding address(es) 'http://0.0.0.0:5222, https://0.0.0.0:7118'. Binding to endpoints defined via IConfiguration and/or UseKestrel() instead.
and it launches on the right Url.
and yes, I have tried to clean solution

Obviously, the port is override, I'm afraid you could check the Program.cs file to see whether there's any other configurations. Is there any other issue?

normally speaking, we always use VS which should follow the launchsetting configurations for running the app, we don't use Kestrel. But in your description, your api is now hosting with another port which doesn't appear in launchsetting, so that I deduce that you might have some other configurations.

@TinyWang there isn't any other configurations. I have removed the endpoints from appsettings.json and I have tried this command: dotnet run --launch-profile https --project Project_Name

and I got this output:
The launch profile "https" could not be applied.
A launch profile with the name 'https' doesn't exist.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:5222
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
Now listening on: https://0.0.0.0:7118
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Content root path: C:\Users\Hossa\source\repos\Portal\Portal.Server

could you pls share more details about , what kind of api you are troubleshooting, the related content in Program.cs and appsetting.json if they had. and how you run the app, with CLI or IDE... this is just a hosting port issue according to the issue description.

@TinyWang .NET Core 8 Api, I run it with IDE but IDE does not show https profile and runs on https://localhost:54854, so I tried to specify the launch profile using CLI

@TinyWang Program.cs contains Services Registration and if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();
app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseFileServer();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapHub("/hubs/ChatHub");
app.Run();

could you pls provide a minimal sample? according to your information, nothing wrong within your app.

the problem was I took a copy of launchsettings.json and was looking at this copy which is in the root project directory not the one in Properties folder

can this case answer your new issue? https://stackoverflow.com/a/76739484
